# bang bang (!!) apparently not working inside ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, rlang

This is a very strange issue, other users got this code to run smoothly. But it is not working for me. I don't understand, perhaps a problem with the version of the packages. I am running R 3.4.4, tidyverse 1.2.1, and rlang 0.2.0

The code is the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
Q <- as_tibble(data.frame(series = rep(c("diax","diay"),3),
                          value = c(3.25,3.30,3.31,3.36,3.38,3.42),
                          year = c(2018,2018,2019,2019,2020,2020))) %>%
  select(year, series, value) %>% spread(key = "series", value = "value") %>%
  rename(`2018-01-01` = diax, `2017-01-01` = diay)

nomes <- c("2018-01-01","2017-01-01")
ggplot(Q, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = !!as.name(nomes[1])), col = "red", size = 2, linetype = "dotdash") +
  geom_line(aes(y = !!as.name(nomes[2])), col = "orange", size = 2, linetype = "dashed")
```

Alternatively, it should also work this way:

```
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)

Q <- as_tibble(data.frame(series = rep(c("diax","diay"),3),
                          value = c(3.25,3.30,3.31,3.36,3.38,3.42),
                          year = c(2018,2018,2019,2019,2020,2020))) %>%
  select(year, series, value) %>% spread(key = "series", value = "value") %>%
  rename(`2018-01-01` = diax, `2017-01-01` = diay)

nomes <- c("2018-01-01","2017-01-01")

    ggplot(Q, aes(x = year)) +
      geom_line(aes(y = !!as.name(nomes[1])), col = "red", size = 2, linetype = "dotdash") +
      geom_line(aes(y = !!as.name(nomes[2])), col = "orange", size = 2, linetype = "dashed")


    ggplot(Q, aes(x = year)) +
      geom_line(aes(y = !!rlang::sym(nomes[1])), col = "red", size = 2, linetype = "dotdash") +
      geom_line(aes(y = !!rlang::sym(nomes[2])), col = "orange", size = 2, linetype = "dashed")
```

The issue is that I keep receiving the following errors message:

```
Error in !as.name(nomes[1]) : invalid argument type

Error in !rlang::sym(nomes[1]) : invalid argument type
```

Comment: It is working in the developement version see here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md

Comment: Confirm that it works for me with the latest dev version

Comment: Thanks Claus WIlke, I was find it very odd, because several people reported that it was working perfectly. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This will be supported as of ggplot2 2.3.0, which is currently being prepared for release.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
Q <- as_tibble(data.frame(series = rep(c("diax","diay"),3),
                          value = c(3.25,3.30,3.31,3.36,3.38,3.42),
                          year = c(2018,2018,2019,2019,2020,2020))) %>%
  select(year, series, value) %>% spread(key = "series", value = "value") %>%
  rename(`2018-01-01` = diax, `2017-01-01` = diay)

nomes <- c("2018-01-01","2017-01-01")
ggplot(Q, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = !!as.name(nomes[1])), col = "red", size = 2, linetype = "dotdash") +
  geom_line(aes(y = !!as.name(nomes[2])), col = "orange", size = 2, linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> Session info -------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
#>  system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       America/Chicago             
#>  date     2018-05-12
#> Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package    * version    date       source                          
#>  assertthat   0.2.0      2017-04-11 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  backports    1.1.2      2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  base       * 3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  bindr        0.1.1      2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  bindrcpp     0.2        2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  colorspace   1.4-0      2017-12-23 R-Forge (R 3.5.0)               
#>  compiler     3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  curl         3.1        2017-12-12 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  datasets   * 3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  devtools     1.13.5     2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  digest       0.6.15     2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  dplyr      * 0.7.4      2017-09-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  evaluate     0.10.1     2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  ggplot2    * 2.2.1.9000 2018-05-12 local                           
#>  glue         1.2.0      2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  graphics   * 3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  grDevices  * 3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  grid         3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  gtable       0.2.0      2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  htmltools    0.3.6      2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  httr         1.3.1      2017-08-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  knitr        1.20       2018-02-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  labeling     0.3        2014-08-23 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  lazyeval     0.2.1      2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  magrittr     1.5        2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  memoise      1.1.0      2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  methods    * 3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  mime         0.5        2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  munsell      0.4.3      2016-02-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  pillar       1.2.1      2018-02-27 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  pkgconfig    2.0.1      2017-03-21 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  plyr         1.8.4      2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  purrr        0.2.4      2017-10-18 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  R6           2.2.2      2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  Rcpp         0.12.16    2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  rlang        0.2.0.9001 2018-05-10 Github (r-lib/rlang@ccdbd8b)    
#>  rmarkdown    1.9        2018-03-01 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  rprojroot    1.3-2      2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  scales       0.5.0.9000 2018-04-10 Github (hadley/scales@d767915)  
#>  stats      * 3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  stringi      1.1.7      2018-03-12 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  stringr      1.3.0      2018-02-19 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  tibble       1.4.2      2018-01-22 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  tidyr      * 0.8.0      2018-01-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  tidyselect   0.2.4      2018-02-26 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  tools        3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  utils      * 3.5.0      2018-04-24 local                           
#>  withr        2.1.2      2018-05-10 Github (jimhester/withr@79d7b0d)
#>  xml2         1.2.0      2018-01-24 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
#>  yaml         2.1.18     2018-03-08 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
```

Comment: Honestly, I think hadley should bite the bullet and release ggplot3 :D

Comment: I confirm that this is now supported